# Add empty rows in a tableviewer

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I want to use a "Add" button to add empty rows in the table using table viewer. After adding a new row, the user can edit it. How can I implement this design? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should add the rows to the data that your content provider returns in the `getElements` method using something that the label provider will show as empty. You then call `refresh` on the table.

For editing you will use the normal `EditingSupport` and make sure it can deal with empty entries.